# How to increase performance of a computer?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, performance

Currently I use Lenovo G62 laptop which runs on Windows 7 Home Premium. It has a 3 GB RAM and Intel i5 processor. Also Ubuntu 12.04 is installed along side Windows.

For some days my laptop is really slow. It takes more time to boot and applications to open. When asked to friends, they told about some softwares to improve system performance.

Which software is best to increase the performance ? I would like to have a free and advanced software with the most number features.

Comment: Buy some memory.

Comment: Or upgrade your CPU, add an SSD, etc.

Comment: You're not interested in making sure there is no malware causing performance issues? Or a virus? If software is out of the question, then you are left with only hardware upgrades.

Comment: @CharlieRB No malware or virus is causing any problem because I use Avast antivirus.

Comment: you should use appropriate software to discover the reason for the issue (eg are you out of ram, how hot is your CPU, what is your average CPU load, is your hdd healthy, etc), and then take appropriate action (buy ram, clean out dust, shut down running programs, replace disk, etc).

Comment: @Tom, it is not safe to assume you have no malware just because you have an antivirus suite.

Comment: Not all antivirus programs remove malware/spyware/adware. You should really consider running something specific to it like [SUPERAntispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/). Malicious software can play havoc on your system performance.

Comment: Slow down time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run msconfig and disable all autostart except some absoultely needed programs.
Use an uninstaller that searches for leftover files from uninstalled programs after their uninstall (I use Revo Uninstaller but there might be better). Use this program to free up disk space. It is not very known but the best of its kind: http://odkurzacz.en.softonic.com/download

Remove viruses and use better antivirus, update all your ware like firmware (including bios), defrag hdd (not flash / ssd). Using linux will be most likely better than windows.

Comment: ytf is this downvoted?!

Comment: Probably because the OP asked how to do this *without* software and you suggested using software. Even though you are correct, it's not what the OP ask. Don't worry about it too much, it's only one vote. Besides the OP marked your answer as accepted. That's worth a lot more than one down vote.

Comment: I didn't give the downvote, but I can see why someone would. This answer gives vague steps toward an undefined resolution for a vague problem statement. This should have been a comment.

Comment: I agree with CharlieRB, while this is not incorrect, it doesn't answer the question and is quite vague.

Comment: Telling the user to adjust what is started when the user logs into Windows is a perfectly valid answer.  The rest of the answer sucks though.